# How to update a .NET Core solution using the dotnet CLI on Azure Devops Pipeline?

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

I have a solutions called Boost.Core.sln with a single project in it. I want to update the packages in the project using the dotnet CLI.

I can get a list of packages like this:

```
C:\Users\RedEase\Source\Repos\Boost.Core\Boost.Core>dotnet list Boost.Core.sln package
Project 'Boost.Core' has the following package references
   [net5.0]:
   Top-level Package            Requested   Resolved
   > Boost.Core.AspNetCore      0.0.1       0.0.1
   > Boost.Core.UI              0.0.2       0.0.2
   > Boost.Core.Utils           0.0.4       0.0.4
```

The Boost.Core.AspNetCore project is at version 0.0.10 now. I want to upgrade the project from 0.0.1 to 0.0.10 but it needs to be scripted and I don't know the exact version number I am upgrading to beforehand. I want to do it with the dotnet command line tool and not with nuget.exe directly.

I am trying to do this from an Azure Devops Pipeline.

(I am open to a different direction if needed.) Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

https://ardalis.com/how-do-i-update-a-nuget-package-using-dotnet-cli/ says that the `dotnet add package` command already does that:

```
dotnet add package Boost.Core.AspNetCore project.csproj
```

Comment: Yes, it does it. I am trying to do this from an Azure Devops Pipeline or even from a command line on my own computer outside of Visual Studio. 

I've realized that dotnet CLI is a Visual Studio tool, so it's not possible to do what I want on a pipeline.

Comment: Uh... `dotnet` is not a VS tool. It's a standalone CLI application. [Here are some examples of running any dotnet command in your azure devops pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnetfive#build-your-project)